# profile2_save($profile) not saving changes to profile

Tags: users, hooks

I'm trying to sort a field collection within a user profile2 profile. Everything works fine, as it should except saving the changes back to the profile.

I'm using the following in a module to sort by client name:

```
function field_collection_sort_user_update($profile){

    global $user;
    $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'my_profile2_profile');
    $engagements = $profile->field_engagements['und'];

    foreach ($engagements as $engagement){
        $engagement_id = $engagement['value'];
        $client_tid = field_collection_item_load($engagement_id)->field_engagement_client['und'][0]['tid'];
        $client_name = taxonomy_term_load($client_tid)->name;
        $clients[] = $client_name;
    }

    foreach ($engagements as $key => $item) {
        $engagements[$key]['sortfield'] = $clients[$key];
    }

    usort($engagements, function($a, $b) {return strcmp($a['sortfield'], $b['sortfield']);});

    foreach ($engagements as $key => $item) {
        unset($engagements[$key]['sortfield']);
    }

    $profile->field_engagements['und'] = $engagements;

    profile2_save($profile);
}
```

No matter what I try, the changes do not save to the profile. I've tried calling different hooks assuming there might be some kind of clash - hook_user_update and hook profile2_presave are called without issue, the sorting and updating of the array/object are fine, but the save never sticks.

Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: I'm gonna say it's impossible...